# wxWidgets: How to change and display content of sizer

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

In my code I've own `MyFrame` class where I create `wxGridSizer` which contains `wxBitmapToggleButton` pointers. After calling `MyFrame` constructor everything works fine, but when I need to change sizer content (using one of event functions) I can see only one `wxBitmapToggleButton` object.

```cpp
class MyFrame : public wxFrame {
public:
    MyFrame();
private:
    // own classes needed in application
    GameBoard *gb;
    Player* player;
    bool lightTheme;
    wxGridSizer *gridSizer; // sizer which contains these buttons
    std::vector<wxBitmapToggleButton *> cardImages; // stores wxBitmapToggleButtons pointers managed by gridSizer
    void OnCardSelect(wxCommandEvent& event); // event function
    void displayImages(); // function which adds wxBitmapToggleButtons to sizer
};

MyFrame::MyFrame() : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "SET Card Game") {
    // ...
    // init GameBoard, Player and lightTheme
    topSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    gridSizer = new wxGridSizer(4, 6, 0, 0);
    displayImages(); // create and display wxBitmapToggleButtons in sizer
    // ...
    // some other layout
    topSizer -> Add(gridSizer);
    this -> SetSizer(topSizer);
    topSizer -> Fit(this);
    topSizer -> SetSizeHints(this);
}

void MyFrame::OnCardSelect(wxCommandEvent& event) {
    wxBitmapToggleButton *selectedCard = dynamic_cast<wxBitmapToggleButton *>(event.GetEventObject());
    player -> toggleChosen(int(selectedCard -> GetId()));
    if(player -> readyToCheck()) {
        const std::vector<int> chosen = player -> getChosen();
        for(int card : chosen) {
            cardImages[card] -> SetValue(false);
            player -> toggleChosen(card);
        }
        if(gb -> isOk(chosen)) {
            // do some modifications on GameBoard
            displayImages();
        }
    }
}
// most important method, it should display card images stored in GameBoard
void MyFrame::displayImages() {
    const std::vector<Card> table = gb -> getTable();
    for(wxBitmapToggleButton* ptr : cardImages) {
    // delete all old wxBitmapToggleButtons from sizer
        gridSizer -> Detach(ptr);
        ptr -> Destroy();
    }
    cardImages.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++) {
        wxBitmap bmp = getCardImage(table[i].getCode(), lightTheme, 0.1); // load image
        cardImages.push_back(new wxBitmapToggleButton(this, i, bmp, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(bmp.GetWidth() + 10, bmp.GetHeight() + 10))); // create wxBitmapTogglebutton from loaded image ...
        gridSizer -> Add(cardImages[i], 0, wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wxALL, 5); // ... and add it to sizer
        this -> Connect(i, wxEVT_TOGGLEBUTTON, wxCommandEventHandler(MyFrame::OnCardSelect)); // connect created button to event
    }
}
```

These images shows result only after calling constructor, and after calling event function:
https://postimg.cc/gallery/uzc2zmii/

Comment: do you know what should be displayed? Or you need to change the content dynamically? If its the former - just create extra control, hide it and then show it when needed.

Comment: I think you just need to call Layout(); at the end of your displayImages() method.

Comment: Thanks `New Pagodi`, that solved the problem! It is my first program in wxWidgets so I didn't know that function.

Comment: @NewPagodi You should make that an answer, so it can be accepted...

Comment: Yes, and @username16 should mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to call [Layout();](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_sizer.html#a1ea8589882944f8ac78b6ff8abde1554) at the end of your displayImages() method.  As the documentation states:

> Call this to force layout of the children anew, e.g. after having added a child to or removed a child (window, other sizer or space) from the sizer

Also, in the displayImages method I think you might be able to just call `gridSizer->Clear(true);` instead of using the for loop to clean out the previous contents of the sizer.